# Factory of base object and inherit object base on string without using cast in java

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose that we have:

```
abstract class Item {   public Item(){}}
abstract class ExtraItem extends Item {  public ExtraItem(){}}
class A extends Item{ public A(){}}
class B extends Item{ public B(){}}
class C extends Item{ public C(){}}
class EA extends ExtraItem{ public A(){}}
class EB extends ExtraItem{ public B(){}}
class EC extends ExtraItem{ public C(){}}
```

I want to write factory class like this but without casting:

```
   class Factory {

       Item createItem(String className){
                Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
                return (Item) clazz.newInstance(); //I don't want here cast to Item    
    }
    ExtraItem createExtraItem(String className){
               Class<? extends ExtraItem> clazz = (Class<? extends ExtraItem>)   Class.forName(className); // I don't want here cast to Extraitem
                return clazz.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

I try write it as above (of course with cast):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Item> T createItem(String protocolType) {
    try {
        String className = protocolType;
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);                        
        return (T) clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ItemFactory", "Lack key \"" + protocolType + "\" in map: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

but how use here Class.cast() method? It a better way?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's simply that you don't like the compiler warnings then you can use `Class.asSubclass` to do the check for you:

```
Class<? extends Item> clazz = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Item.class);
```

And the same principle for `ExtraItem`. This will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if the class named is not actually a subclass of `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid cast, when you pass the className in string. As you do not have type i will create a `Class<?>` and the `newInstance()` will result with `Object`.

If you do not want to cast, you should pass Class instance of class you want to create a instance.

Beside the cast is normal operation, so avoiding it do not have much sence. Remember most of the code works as you programmet it to work. If you are sure that passsed string can create classes that inherit `Item`, the you can cast without any unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cast at all change your method signatures to:

```
class Factory {
    <T extends Item> T createItem(Class<T> itemClass) {
        try {
            return itemClass.newInstance();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    <T extends ExtraItem> T createExtraItem(Class<T> itemClass) {
        return createItem(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have only name of class. In string.